# What is the suspension of finer particles in the air called when a powdery substance is poured?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a verb that describes the formation of the mist-kind of cloud of finer flour particulates when it is poured.

Sample sentence:

> As soon as I poured the flour into the mixing bowl, it started to "verb".

Like Champagne or soda water "sparkle" and carbonated drinks "fizz".

Comment: Among other odd jobs, I designed, built and tested a dust collection system for a flour mill, and I have no idea what you call this process. A consensus for such a term is highly unlikely.

Comment: Somewhat perversely, we have a verb for separating the aerosol into solids and air - de-entrainment. So you might guess that entrainment would mean forming an aerosol, but it doesn't.

Comment: @PhilSweet: In chemical terms, the answer for the question in the title is "aerosol". The verb form would be "aerosolize" (as stated in my other answer). It's not informal, but it accurately describes what OP wants.

Comment: Sure, but some words work *alot* better as past tense forms that focus on the results - aerosolized - than in the inceptional case - starting to aerosolize. There are no instances of "starting to aerosolize" and two instances of "begin to aerosolize" in Google. That's awfully thin evidence.

Comment: @PhilSweet: Come to think of it, you're right. I edited my answer to include the past tense and present participle (of "aerosolize") which have more results on Google.

Comment: It makes a *dust cloud*, but that is neither a verb nor one word.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> As soon as I poured the flour into the mixing bowl, it started to **billow** out.

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/billow) has

> **billow**
> <sub>VERB</sub>
>
> **1.1** move or flow outward with an undulating motion.

---

The question asks for a verb but the title suggests a noun, and this word can be either.

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/billow) has

> **billow**
> **3** COUNTABLE NOUN
>
> A billow of smoke or dust is a large mass of it rising slowly into the air.

Comment: Not the right answer. Flour does not billow, this is something we say about [smoke, steam,  that stretches over a large area](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/billow). Billowing bed sheets hanging to dry, sails  billow in the wind etc. Not flour, not pollen, nor seeds.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Collins and I am not the only ones who know this word. Please see [Hough Mill Today](https://swannington-heritage.co.uk/windmills/hough-mill-today/) which says *One set of stones is enclosed in a wooden tun so that the flour does not billow out across the floor.* I agree that sheets and sails also billow, but I didn't mention pollen or seeds. IMO your *disperse* does not work: the floating flour would disperse some time later.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I agree that billow isn't THE word meaning precisely what they asked for, but it's the word we've long use for it.

Comment: Flour *dust* billows. But most people are not familiar with the term; they would refer to it as just *flour*. So when people say, "Hey look at all that flour billowing!", they are actually referring to flour *dust*. So it's perfectly acceptable to use "billow" here; "a billow of flour [dust] is a large mass of it rising slowly into the air".

Comment: I would consider "billow" more appropriate for a mass that is settling than a dust that is wafting into the air.

Comment: @Mark Ransom "billowing" matter requires an expansion.  So settling would not apply unless it is extremely cold to the point of thermocline and is spilling over a lower surface. At ankle or knee height, say. OP may be looking for the equivalent of colloidal suspension, air being a fluid.

Answer (score 16):

Although not a verb, you could use the word ***puff***  (as in "a puff of flour"):

> **puff**
> <sub>*noun*</sub>
>
> a small amount of smoke, air, or something that can rise into the air in a small cloud
>
> ([Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/puff))

---

> There's something special about a homemade pizza — the **puff of flour**, rolling the dough and the fresh ingredients.
>
> ([Pinterest](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/256986722473489751/))

> “Very good!” The baker claps her hands together, releasing a **fine puff of flour**.
>
> ([builtincolorado.com](https://www.builtincolorado.com/blog/lesson-loaf-bread))

> [image]
>
> ([industrial-maid.com](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Findustrial-maid.com%2Fapplications%2Feliminating-flour-dust%2F&psig=AOvVaw2nkjZVqaOUJHVtuwps4n2U&ust=1648996588878000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAwQjhxqFwoTCND--JjN9fYCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD))

The effect is similar to when you're using a powder puff to apply makeup.

---

> As soon as I poured the flour into the mixing bowl, a [fine] **puff** of flour was released.

> [image]
>
> ([hse.gov.uk](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.hse.gov.uk%2Ffood%2Flow-flour-dust.htm&psig=AOvVaw1SU-QDFNnDBljcFruhZGoj&ust=1649002817120000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAwQjhxqFwoTCKCX3K_k9fYCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAO))

Comment: For the benefit of non-native speakers: Flour or dust doesn't puff. Souffles, [(puff) pastries](https://www.thekitchn.com/kitchen-mysteries-what-makes-p-108154), yorkshire puddings  and some cakes can *puff* or *puff up* in a hot oven, but never flour by itself. On the other hand, *puff(s) of flour* is quite idiomatic.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Thanks, I've edited my answer. The word is better used as a noun as in "puff of flour" rather than a verb as in "started to puff".

Comment: @Mari-LouA I absolutely would say flour could puff

Comment: @Tristan I would absolutely say "Puffs of flour appeared when the packet was emptied/poured"

Comment: I think flour dust both puffs and billows. I also think there's not a specific word to answer the OP's question in a universal way.

Comment: @Mari-LouA "some of the flour puffed into the air as I poured it into the bowl" seems entirely reasonable to me, and "flour dust" certainly can. Maybe there are regional differences? I'm from SE England

Comment: @Tristan  That's a good workaround. It doesn't match the OP's sentence but it works all the same.

Answer (score 16):

Pollen, dust, and all powder particles *travel*, *spread* and become *suspended* in the air. One verb that incorporates this phenomenon is *disperse*

> As soon as I poured the flour into the mixing bowl, it started to **disperse** in the air.

> **disperse** VERB
> Distribute or spread over a wide area.
> • ‘Spores are dispersed passively by wind and rain.’
> *[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/disperse)*

Examples of usage taken from Google Books

- Lightweight flour is very easy to **[disperse in the air](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Intelligent_Manufacturing_and_Mechatroni/KRg0EAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=flour%20disperse%20%22in%20the%20air%22&pg=PA1313&printsec=frontcover)**
- A child is likely to put a spoon or hand in a bowl of flour , without any notion of [**how flour disperses**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22how%20flour%20disperses%22&biw=1440&bih=744&tbm=bks&sxsrf=APq-WBsoCyemVLpzyYWmwgc8EjAlxXFDrg%3A1648932095837&ei=_7RIYofMMrfg7_UPlp25wA4&ved=0ahUKEwjHx9Lenvb2AhU38LsIHZZODugQ4dUDCAk&uact=5&oq=%22how%20flour%20disperses%22&gs_lcp=Cg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzEANQqAtYhx5gmiRoAHAAeACAAWeIAY0CkgEDMi4xmAEAoAEBwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz-books), and to end up with a transformed , thoroughly floured torso!
- like wheat flour, rice flour, paper, wood, sugar, etc., are highly flammable [when **dispersed** in the air](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Mechanism_of_Fires/ZltcEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=flour%20disperse%20%22in%20the%20air%22&pg=PA197&printsec=frontcover) as a fine cloud of particles.

Comment: This is it. Dispersal describes the process of becoming an aerosol. Most other answers describe processes involving already dispersed aerosols.

Answer (score 8):

> As soon as I poured the flour into the mixing bowl, it started to "puther".

OED **puther**

> **3. intransitive. Usually in form puther. Chiefly English regional (northern and midlands) and Scottish. To move in a cloud, as smoke, dust, etc.; to roll, pour, billow.**
>
> 2004   C. Brown Of Ghosts & Faeries 212   *They..were carrying on with their conversations despite the black smoke puthering from the gap under the cellar door.*

I'm not sure how widely known the verb is currently, but what you are looking for is a relatively informal verb, and this is.

Comment: I think I can safely say that it is not widely known currently.

Comment: I certainly didn't know that word, but it sure is fine as frog's hair! It is going right in my word-hoard.

Answer (score 7):

You could also use ***aerosolize***, which is a more accurate (chemical) term and is used as a verb:

> **aerosolize**
> <sub>*transitive verb*</sub>
>
> : to disperse (something) as an aerosol: to convert or form into an aerosol
>
> ([Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aerosolize))

---

> The flour **aerosolized**<sup>1</sup> as soon as I poured it into the mixing bowl.

So when you pour the flour into the mixing bowl, it gets dispersed as an [aerosol](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aerosol), which, in case of flour, is a cloud or suspension of fine flour particles that can spread in the air.

---

Image of aerosolized flour / flour dust (highlighted):

> [image]
>
> ([hse.gov.uk](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.hse.gov.uk%2Ffood%2Flow-flour-dust.htm&psig=AOvVaw1SU-QDFNnDBljcFruhZGoj&ust=1649002817120000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAwQjhxqFwoTCKCX3K_k9fYCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAT))

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> "started to aerosolize" or "started aerosolizing" can also be used, but it works best when the verb is used in the past tense.</sup>

Comment: I would use aerosolize over the words in other answers if I were writing a patent or other legal document, but I probably wouldn't use it in any casual setting

Comment: I don't love this answer (because there is no colloidal suspension here and the top line asserts this is an accurate chemical term), and then I went looking.  The Wikipedia article on aerosols states "The liquid or solid particles have diameters typically less than 1 μm; larger particles with a significant settling speed make the mixture a suspension, but the distinction is not clear-cut." which at least has some ambiguity, but not accuracy.  The distribution of milled flour particle size is apparently 17 μm to 354 μm which makes this even less clear.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerosol

Answer (score 3):

I'd call it a **Cloud**, much like you might say *"A cloud of dust is rolling in off the fields because of all that spring wind"*.

@GRem is correct in quoting the National Fire Protection Agency (NFPA) standards, a cloud of things like flour or fine metal dust is *extremely* dangerous.  But, aerosols and vapors really pertain to dispersed fine liquid droplets (aerosols) or gaseous materials (typically the result of a phase transition from liquid, and that may contain aerosolized droplets as well).

For a verb, I would tend to use **Disperse**. *"When Bill dropped that 50 lb bag of flour, it cracked open and a cloud of flour dispersed, coating everything in a white powdery film"*

Comment: A little more research (by me) lends more weight to _aerosol_.  During my years as a Chemical Engineering student, that noun was purely used to describe liquid particulates, not solid ones.  This NASA article (https://www.nasa.gov/centers/langley/news/factsheets/Aerosols.html) makes a good case for calling desert dust clouds/plumes _aerosols_.  That's basically analogous to flour entrained in air.  Again, be real careful with this stuff; flour processing is up there with gasoline refining in terms of fire and explosion hazards

Comment: Yes, but in the context of the question the OP was asking for a verb, not a noun.

Comment: The title asks for a noun (_what is the suspension of finer particles_), though the description does specify a verb

Comment: Yep, good point...

Answer (score 2):

In addition to other mentioned answers I think a "plume of flour" should likely work though references I checked associate "plume" more with feather-like stuff, i.e.

From WordNet (r) 3.0 (2006) [wn]:

> plume
> n 1: anything that resembles a feather in shape or lightness; "a plume of smoke"; "grass with large plumes"
> ...

---

While it escapes me how smoke resembles a feather in shape or lightness in the cited example, that's the usage I've been reminded of given your question.

Comment: Good answer; You can see how it is used in different contexts [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22plume+of+flour%22). [For example](https://familyeats.net/bread-therapy/): *As I lightly dust the counter, a small **plume of flour** creates a momentary cloud of dust in the air before settling on the counter, the floor, [...]*

Answer (score 2):

There are some good answers here, but I am surprised that nobody has offered that the best choice depends on the use, or intent.

For example, if you were seeking to publish a factual report on a study you performed to determine flammable characteristics of various concentrations of airborne flour particles you might choose more scientifically correct terminology such as: "As soon as I poured the flour into the mixing bowl, it started to **disperse** into an airborne cloud with opacity measured at..."

Whereas if you were writing a romance novel where the main character had just poured his love interest a glass of wine and was attempting to impress her by making pasta from scratch you might choose: "As soon as I poured the flour into the mixing bowl, it started to **blossom** into the air, like our feelings for each other..."

Answer (score 0):

> The National Fire Protection Agency (NFPA) defines combustible dust as “a finely divided combustible particulate solid that presents a flash-fire hazard or explosion hazard when suspended in air or the process-specific oxidizing medium over a range of concentrations” in Standard 652-2019, The Fundamentals of ...

> Flour explodes when its particles become suspended in the air in a dust cloud and are then ignited. The starch molecules burn relatively quickly, and it is their rapid expansion in the presence of heat that causes an explosion.

> If the spread of flame is at subsonic speed, the phenomenon is sometimes called a "deflagration", although looser usage calls both phenomena "explosions". Dust explosions may be classified as being either "primary" or "secondary" in nature.

I guess what is carried or picked up by the air or whatever.  Aerosolization, in a way.

Edit:  I guess that vaporize is the intransitive verb.  Vapor is "a substance diffused or suspended in the air, especially one normally liquid or solid."

> vapor noun
>
> Definition of vapor
>
> 1 : diffused matter (such as smoke or fog)
> suspended floating in the air and impairing its
> transparency
>
> 2a : a substance in the gaseous state as
> distinguished from the liquid or solid state
>
> b : a substance (such as gasoline, alcohol,
> mercury, or benzoin) vaporized for industrial,
> therapeutic, or military uses also : a mixture
> (such as the explosive mixture in an internal
> combustion engine) of such a vapor with air
>
> 3a : something unsubstantial or transitory :
> phantasm
>
> b : a foolish or fanciful idea
>
> 4 vapors plural a archaic : exhalations of bodily
> organs (such as the stomach) held to affect the
> physical or mental condition
>
> b : a depressed or hysterical nervous condition

> vaporize verb
>
> Definition of vaporize
>
> transitive verb
>
> 1 : to convert (as by the application of heat or by
> spraying) into vapor
>
> 2 : to cause to become dissipated
>
> 3 : to destroy by or as if by converting into vapor
> a tank vaporized by a shell
>
> intransitive verb
>
> 1 : to become vaporized
>
> 2 : vapor sense 2

Anyway, the point of the above exercise was to put a word for the formation or structure involved, not, the rising or otherwise moving through the air, function of.  As water may vaporize, then flour, too.

----------> Now to compare the definition of vapor, to that of aerosol.

> aerosol noun
>
> Definition of aerosol
>
> 1 : a suspension of fine solid or liquid particles
> in gas Smoke, fog, and mist are aerosols. airborne
> aerosol transmission of infective viral particles
> also aerosols plural : the fine particles of an
> aerosol stratospheric aerosols
>
> 2 : a substance (such as an insecticide or
> medicine) dispensed from a pressurized container as
> an aerosol also : the container for this

> As nouns the difference between vapour and aerosol
> is that vapour is cloudy diffused matter such as
> mist, steam or fumes suspended in the air while
> aerosol is a liquid or solid composed of finely
> divided particles suspended in a gaseous medium.
>
> As a verb vapour is to become vapour; to be emitted
> or circulated as vapour or vapour can be to become
> vapour; to be emitted or circulated as vapour.

It seems that the two words are basically the same, with the same examples for each, but with vapor keying in on the whole, a cloud, and, aerosol keying in on the parts, the finely divided particles.

Now is flour either?  I looked up some particle sizes.  Generally, fog is 0 up to 30 microns; mist runs from about 70 to about 350 microns; and, milled floor from about 1 to 100 microns.  Smoke particles tend to be much smaller on average, but get up to about 50 microns from burning some substances.  Likely, it's reasonable to assume that it's the smaller particles of each that suspend the easiest, such as from simply pouring a substance.  Regardless, milled flour is in the usual range of stuff generally considered an aerosol, or vapor.

Interestingly, there are aerosol non-stick coating products that employ real flour.

> Pam Baking Spray combines the no-stick power of Pam with real flour for a baking spray that reaches every nook and cranny. No need to grease and flour your bakeware! Plus, spray Pam Baking Spray on your baking sheets, pans and cookware to make cleanup easier. Bake your favorite recipes without artificial preservatives, colors or flavors. Prepare delicious cakes, cupcakes, brownies, muffins and more. With this no-stick spray, your baked goods will look great when they're easily removed from the pan. Pam Baking Spray has 0 calories and no fat per serving.

One other point.  The human eye can detect particles larger than about 50 to 100 microns.

See the sizes of some different fine particles at https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/particle-sizes-d_934.html

Disclaimer:  Please note that sizes vary a bit, sometimes a lot, depending on the variation in each type of particle, and, on the source of the information.

---

Final edit:  I think that ... Something may expand, spread, disperse, etc, only in the medium in which it naturally exists.  Smoke billows because it's already in the air, but, not flour because flour isn't already in the air, it doesn't come in the air.  Only a cloud of flour can billow, or so disperse, and the like.  Flour may disperse, say, in/into a mixing bowl, but, not in/into the air.  Flour isn't per se a cloud of flour.  We don't think of clouds when we think of flour.  Similarly, only a solution of flour can disperse in water.  A crowd of people may disperse in/into the streets.  Perhaps to be swept up by a tornado, and, then, "billowed", or so dispersed, back to the ground to be dedispersed to a ____ (word for group?) of dead human bodies.

Anyway, just my take on it.  Creative venting, in a way.

Comment: *Aerosolize* is more suitable than *vaporize* here. Vapor almost always refers to the gas phase, whereas the material here is a suspended solid.

Comment: I think the diffused nature of the definition of vapor might exclude flour in that (with good vision) one can usually see the tiny flour particles that make up the cloud, but I suppose it's probably on the blurry line and I'm probably just making up excuses to justify my feeling that it sounds wrong to me to say flour vapor.